# Anthology of texts on semiotics

Tags: reference-request, semiotics

It might be rather unusual question but I'm looking for a book that I once saw several years ago. It was a multivolume anthology of texts on semiotics. I remember that there were some Peirce and Barthes works inside amongst others. One curious thing about the book - it was not so much a collection of complete essays, but a selection of essential fragments from different sources - so, if I recall, there were some pieces from Peirce earlier and later works next to each other.

I'm searching for it for some time but with no luck. Queries like “semiotics anthology”, “theory of sign, anthology” etc. didn’t give me what I’m looking for. I would appreciate any help. Maybe some of you know the book and could aid me here.

Comment: [Innis, Semiotics, An Introductory Anthology](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Semiotics/Wu2Ld0cQmyIC?hl=en)?

Comment: Welcome to SE. This is a long shot, but I'm sure you know that. You would have done better to explain why you are looking for this particular book. That way, you might get some help with what you're thinking about or a reference to another book that helps you, even if it isn't the one you are looking for.

Comment: Innis anthology is nice, but unfortunately this is not the book I'm looking for. Thanks anyway.  

Thanks for feedback Ludwig. So, semiotic seems to me to be such a interdisciplinary and vague field that anthology is best suited to get a general understanding of most important branches of it. The book was multivolume, very comprehensive and it was a collection of fragments of texts from various sources, it wasn’t just a collection of essays or other complete pieces of work, but something more of a encyclopaedical flavor.